Configuring SMB Shares on MacOS with /etc/nsmb.conf - Write throttling Issues
Experimenting using some old equipment to serve a 8 bay RAID over 10gbe network, using a 2019 MacPro as a server. This unit is currently running Monterey.
Initial testing yields good results to a MacStudio client using a thunderbolt 10gbe adapter. I'm seeing r/w of around 800/900mbps.
However under sustained load, copying 1TB (and verify) over the network I start to see bandwidth issues the transfer will peak at the above speeds and throttle down to 12/24mbps. It appears to be only on writes, the verification speeds remain high.
I've tested with iPerf3 for extended times and the network seems ok.
I've also tried to configure SMB using /etc/nsmb.conf on the Server and Client. However it appears that OSX is not applying these configs to the share. Even a simple config is not applied, e.g turn off signing. I wanted to test turning off any of these overheads to see if this effected the throttling issue.
On Ventura Client and Monterey Server:
[default]
signing_required=no

When checking the share with smbutil statshares -a Signing is still on, even after a restart on both systems.
Can anyone share some light on this? Is there a second config that takes precedence over the /etc/nsmb.conf?
I've checked the home folder for anything smb related and there is nothing there. The user connecting to the SMB share is a separate (non-privallaged) account on the server.
statshares:
Archive
                              SERVER_NAME                   X.X.X.X
                              USER_ID                       501
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB1_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB2_ENABLED
                              SMB_NEGOTIATE                 SMBV_NEG_SMB3_ENABLED
                              SMB_VERSION                   SMB_3.0.2
                              SMB_ENCRYPT_ALGORITHMS        AES_128_CCM_ENABLED
                              SMB_ENCRYPT_ALGORITHMS        AES_128_GCM_ENABLED
                              SMB_ENCRYPT_ALGORITHMS        AES_256_CCM_ENABLED
                              SMB_ENCRYPT_ALGORITHMS        AES_256_GCM_ENABLED
                              SMB_CURR_ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM    OFF
                              SMB_SHARE_TYPE                DISK
                              SIGNING_SUPPORTED             TRUE
                              SIGNING_REQUIRED              TRUE
                              EXTENDED_SECURITY_SUPPORTED   TRUE
                              UNIX_SUPPORT                  TRUE
                              LARGE_FILE_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              OS_X_SERVER                   TRUE
                              FILE_IDS_SUPPORTED            TRUE
                              FILE_LEASING_SUPPORTED        TRUE
                              MULTI_CREDIT_SUPPORTED        TRUE
                              DIR_LEASING_SUPPORTED         TRUE
                              ENCRYPTION_SUPPORTED          TRUE
                              SIGNING_ON                    TRUE


Additionally I've captured network traffic and checked for retransmits with Wireshark. I'm not an expert in this area but there was only 3 in a 30 minute period.
